# ASP.Net ASPxGridView OnHtmlDataCellPrepared

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, devexpress

I have a aspx webpage with ASPxGridView. the cells are colored with red or green depending on the cell data.

I need to make a checkbox input on the same page. If the checkbox is checked, the green cells should be filled with white. Unchecking the checkbox reterns to the red/green colored cells.

So far, I made an input checkbox. If checked, it shows alert "checked" if not "unchecked". This is done by javascript.

ASPxGridView has an attribute OnHtmlDataCellPrepared which calls a function to display the data and color the cells to red or green depending on the data.

Is there a way to pass a checked parameter to the function of OnHtmlDataCellPrepared so if checked, the cells are filled with red/white if not they are filled with red/green?

Comment: Is the checkbox outside the grid?

Comment: yes the checkbox is outside the grid

Answer (score 0):

After you check/uncheck your checkbox you can invoke  clientside function Refresh() on your GridView and OnHtmlDataCellPrepared will be fired. Then you can check the checkbox if  it is checked and change the color.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" ClientInstanceName="grid" 
    OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared"  runat="server" >
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Name="SomeName">

        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<dx:ASPxCheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox">
    <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="function(s,e){grid.Refresh();}" />
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

And in C#

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataColumn.Name == "SomeName")
        {
            if (this.checkbox.Checked)
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; // or the color you want
            }

        }
    }
```